# How to change value using add_action WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm working on a currency layer API. So, my client wants to make a custom plugin. I'm working on it but I need a small help. I'm new in making plugins.

Client wants to change currency according to price but default price comes through this way.

```
<span class="prict">[price]</span> example: $345
```

So, how will I change the price which I got from the API and I've stored that value in cookie also.

Please help me doing add_action.

```
add_action('', 'change_price', 10, 3);
function change_price(){ 
}
```

Hook not found I got that span only. Please help me?

Comment: from what is that price span from? a plugin? the name of the plugin?

Comment: Are you using woocommerce plugin in your project??

Comment: No. That's coming from custom fields. I'm not using woocommerce plugins but already had a custom listing manager done by some other developer.

Comment: There is anyway to use the css class
<span class="wlt_shortcode_price">€19.46</span>